# How do I set up the $docroot to give me the path that I want

Tags: php

How can I define `$docroot` path so I can input my own path.

I have the code:

```
$docroot = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT");
```

which when I use it in combination with on my index.php :

**index.php**

```
$docroot = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT");
require_once("access/$template/head.php");
```

And on the required_once linked document `head.php` has the following code:

**head.php**

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='$docroot/$template/css/style.css'>
```

The code above makes :

```
/home/users/web/b192/dom.icorporationus/public_html/blanky-store.net/models/site-templates/rd-web_design-black_colours/css/style.css
```

This is the code that adds

```
/home/users/web/b192/dom.icorporationus/public_html/blanky-store.net/
```

How can I change my `$docroot` so that instead of displaying my full path to my server it will display the path :

```
/access/
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to add the `$docroot` variable to your HTML code at all, since that's the path the server uses. Your template shouldn't reference it.

If this is some code you'd rather not touch, here's how to override it (at the risk of breaking a lot of other code):

```
putenv('DORUMENT_ROOT=');
$docroot='';
```

Of course you need to run it in front of your `index.php` code.

Now a piece of advice:

1. To access static resources, use a helper function to get the full path. (like `get_static('/path/to/resource')`. This makes it easier to relocate your static resources.
2. This way of organizing your pages is horribly outdated and should not be practiced any more. Consider reading up on [modern day PHP applications](http://www.janoszen.com/2013/01/08/writing-modern-day-php-applications/). (Article by me.)

Comment: Hey that worked now if I have the code: <link rel='stylesheet' href='$docroot/$template/css/style.css'> it displays code: <link rel='stylesheet' href='/models/site-templates/rd-web_design-black_colours/css/style.css'> notice the ' / ' how can i get rid of that slash using the d$docroot?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the slash? It references the domain root. Anyway, without changing the `head.php` you can't get rid of it, it's in there. Just look at the code! Or just add whatever you need into the docroot.

Comment: Yea I know without changing the head but how can I do it?

Comment: Listen, no offense, but it's right there. You want this in your output: `/models/site-templates/rd-web_design-black_colours/css/style.css`. Right now you got this: `/rd-web_design-black_colours/css/style.css`. If should be blatantly obvious what you need to add to your docroot variable.