# How do I define $docroot so that it will not display a slash?

Tags: php

Hey how do I define $docroot so that it will not references the domain root?

When I use code:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='$docroot/$template/css/style.css'>
```

This displays code:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/models/site-templates/rd-web_design-black_colours/css/style.css'>
```

Notice the slash at the beginning. That is referencing the domain root. How can I define my $docroot in my document so that it will not display with a slash

**example**

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='models/site-templates/rd-web_design-black_colours/css/style.css'>
```

Comment: `$docroot = 'models';`

Comment: zerkms that did not do you probably did not see the whole code

Comment: @user2555525: you probably asked the question terrible

Comment: Why did you [repost the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516373/how-do-i-set-up-the-docroot-to-give-me-the-path-that-i-want)?

Comment: Then edit it, that's what the edit feature is for. I still stand by my original statement that you need to get a basic understanding how programming works because your question requires nothing more than thinking a bit. You need to put at least some effort into your questions.

Comment: I did I just want to start with no /

Comment: OK, what are the contents of `$template` and `$docroot` for starters?

Comment: $template is a system for templates it is already set up. I have my head, style, header, footer and so on

Comment: Yes, but what is IN `$template`? If you say `echo $template` what does it say?

Answer (score 2):

```
$docroot = ltrim($docroot, '/');
```

**You trim it, of course :)**

*(facepalm)*

```
// remove the slashes from folder
$docroot = trim($docroot, '/');
$template = trim($template, '/');
// and you add the dashes by force joining the URL
echo "{$docroot}/{$template}/css/style.css";
```

Comment: How do you know without knowing the contents of his `$template` and `$docroot` variables?

Comment: No that is still blatantly displaying a slash  :(        <link rel='stylesheet' href='/models/site-templates/rd-web_design-black_colours/css/style.css'>

Comment: a $template displays the code <link rel='stylesheet' href='models/site-templates/rd-web_design-black_colours/css/grid.css'>

Comment: @user2555525 Look at the updated code.

Comment: That did not do it    :)        I am getting the same code

Comment: @user2555525 Post the exact echo you use.

Comment: It still showing as <link rel='stylesheet' href='/models/site-templates/rd-web_design-black_colours/css/style.css'>  even with the trim it is not timing it!!

Answer (score 0):

OK, scraping together your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516373/how-do-i-set-up-the-docroot-to-give-me-the-path-that-i-want) and this one, here's your answer. You clearly don't deserve it though, since you haven't the faintest idea what your code does and why.

Since your `head.php` already contains the slash, you can do one thing: change `$template` to contain only `site-templates/rd-web_design-black_colours` (remove the `models` part) AND change `$docroot` to `models`.

Personally I recommend buying a book on PHP and maybe attenting a course in programming in general to get into the thinking required for debugging problems.

Comment: No!!!   :)      thanks for your help though but I need the models on my $template

Comment: Then you need to change the `head.php` and remove the slash as I already told you before.

Comment: silly enough but you know what can do it is by removing the slash      <link rel='stylesheet' href='$docroot $template/css/style.css'>       I do not like it though but it works

Comment: Yea that did not do it either.....    :(

Comment: Listen, how about you try and think your problem through? Maybe you wouldn't need to open three different questions for the same issue and you'd avoid the downvote-storm too.